# How to confirm the enabled Modules in an Ignite Cluster inside of Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, geospatial, ignite, gridgain

I have setup an Ignite Cluster with the ignite-geospatial module, however it is running into ClassNotFound Exception for H2SpatialIndex, something I know is caused by the lack of the ignite-geospatial module. I am new to Kubernetes and may have configured something wrong, but I am not sure how to check whether my Ignite Nodes have access to this module or not.

Is there any quick commands I can run to validate the classpath for ignite-geospatial?

Here is my Ignite Deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"ignite-cluster","namespace":"ignite"},"spec":{"replicas":2,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"ignite"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"ignite"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"OPTION_LIBS","value":"ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http"},{"name":"CONFIG_URI","value":"file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml"}],"image":"gridgain/community:latest","name":"ignite-node","ports":[{"containerPort":47100},{"containerPort":47500},{"containerPort":49112},{"containerPort":10800},{"containerPort":8080}],"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/ignite/config","name":"config-vol"}]}],"serviceAccountName":"ignite","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":100000,"volumes":[{"configMap":{"name":"ignite-config"},"name":"config-vol"}]}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-15T11:42:44Z"
  generation: 1
  name: ignite-cluster
  namespace: ignite
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http,ignite-geospatial
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
        image: gridgain/community:8.8.27
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: ignite-node
        ports:
        - containerPort: 47100
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 47500
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 49112
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 10800
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /ignite/config
          name: config-vol
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: ignite
      serviceAccountName: ignite
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 100000
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: ignite-config
        name: config-vol
```

My previous deployment YAML did not include the ignite-geospatial value under the OPTION_LIBS, so I have since corrected that and restarted the Ignite Cluster. I can connect to the Ignite Cluster within Kubernetes using a Thick Client with PeerClassEnabled, but I run into the following issue after attempting to load any JTS Geometries. The same error can be found when running everything locally and explicitly omitting the ignite-geospatial module. The error is remedied locally when ignite-geospatial is added to the dependencies.

```
[o.a.i.i.processors.cache.ExchangeActions$CacheGroupActionData@413cde3b]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2SpatialIndex
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2Utils.createSpatialIndex(H2Utils.java:359)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableDescriptor.createUserIndex(H2TableDescriptor.java:442)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableDescriptor.createUserIndexes(H2TableDescriptor.java:392)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.SchemaManager.createTable(SchemaManager.java:554)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.SchemaManager.onCacheTypeCreated(SchemaManager.java:338)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerType(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1979)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.registerCache0(GridQueryProcessor.java:2205)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart0(GridQueryProcessor.java:1048)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart(GridQueryProcessor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1968)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCaches$55a0e703$1(GridCacheProcessor.java:1838)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCachesIfPossible$14(GridCacheProcessor.java:1808)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareStartCaches(GridCacheProcessor.java:1835)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareStartCachesIfPossible(GridCacheProcessor.java:1806)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.processCacheStartRequests(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:1039)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.onCacheChangeRequest(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:925)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onCacheChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1479)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:986)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3416)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3245)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2SpatialIndex
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2Utils.createSpatialIndex(H2Utils.java:343)
        ... 21 more
```

node-configuration.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                        <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
                        <property name="serviceName" value="ignite-service"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ignite service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.serviceName
  name: ignite-service
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.namespace
  namespace: ignite
  labels:
    app: ignite
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: rest
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: thinclients
      port: 10800
      targetPort: 10800
  # Optional - remove 'sessionAffinity' property if the cluster
  # and applications are deployed within Kubernetes
  #  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  selector:
    # Must be equal to the label set for pods.
    app: ignite
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

cluster-role.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ignite 
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ignite 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
```

Comment: Where is the log from? A server node or your thick client?

Comment: @StephenDarlington - The log is from the ignite-cluster pod itself.

Comment: @StephenDarlington do you know of any way to check an Ignite Node for all modules it has access to? Have tried `ignite-geospatial` and `ignite-geospatial-ext` and still encounter the same error.

Comment: How did you create the table? How are you loading the data?

Comment: Hi @StephenDarlington, we are creating Ignite Caches using the Apache Ignite Java Thick Client and loading the data this way as well. In fact, recent tests on Kubernetes demonstrated that everything is working as-expected on version 8.8.13 of GridGain. So somewhere between 8.8.13 and 8.8.27 of GridGain, the ability for an Ignite Cluster to utilize ignite-geospatial for spatial indexing was disrupted, or the configuration prerequisites evolved in a way that is not currently documented.

Comment: Please share your configuration. When I tried, it works.

Comment: I updated original post with cluster, service, and node configuration files. Is there anything else I can provide? Specifically, I am wondering if our inclusion of the ignite-geospatial module is correct. I understand ignite-geospatial was moved to Ignite Extensions in May 2022, may this have impacted the way in which it needs to be included in the ignite deployment YAML?

Answer (score 0):

The latest jars are on https://gridgainsystems.com/nexus/content/repositories/external/org/gridgain/ignite-geospatial/8.8.30/ , and this series started about 2020. Before then , there was a series of libraries under org.apache.ignite.ignite-geospatial, maybe that's the problem.